# How can two machines detect each other when their ips keep changing?

Tags: android, macos, networking, bluetooth, wifi

Let me describe what I want to achieve and where I am stuck. It is okay to suggest an entirely different alternative.

1. I have an Android phone with NFC feature.
2. I have a macbook pro.
3. A wifi network.

Whenever I tap my phone on a certain NFC tag I want my Macbook to run a certain script.

So I did the following

1. An android application that is invoked whenever the device senses a particular NFC tag.
2. My Macbook runs a NodeJS HTTP server
3. Android app sends an HTTP request to NodeJS, NodeJS then invokes whatever script I wanted to run.

This setup works perfectly at my home where I can Set the IP address of my Macbook to whatever I want. But i want the same setup to work transparently when I am in starbucks (or workplace) and both my Android and Macbook are on the same Wifi network. (I dont want to enter the IP addresses manually).

When I was halfway through I realized that I could have used bluetooth feature on the Macbook but then I will probably have to write a sophisticated program on macbook to listen to the Android device and accept commands.

Answer (score 2):

On Android, use [Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html). If you're using an earlier target, [jmDNS](http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html) is your friend. I have only used this to allow android devices to find each other, but this should be compatible with bonjour service on your Mac.

Comment: Cool. This is why I like SO. I would not have found it on my own.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution #1**
Use a network service discovery technology.  I would perhaps suggest [Zero Config](http://www.zeroconf.org/) which Apple implements as "Bonjour"

**Solution #2**
Have a third device with a known IP address for bookkeeping the other devices' IP (essentially what DNS is)

**Solution #3**
Setup your WiFi network to have static IPs : allocating predefined IPs to computer with specific MAC addresses  (that way clients can still have "DHCP" but the router would always allocate the same local IP)

Answer (score -1):

I'd look into dynamic dns.  You can use that to automatically update dns names for a computer that changes IP addresses.